# header files not recognised in C++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, g++, header-files

I have a folder named `apt-util` with header files in include directory. When I tried to compile the source code in which I include these files, it is saying :

```
parseFile.C:17:36: error: apt_util/unicode_utils.h: No such file or directory
```

In my code, I included this file like this:

```cpp
#include <apt_util/unicode_utils.h>
```

How to resolve this error?

I am using Linux OS and compiling using g++.

Comment: You're saying "I have a folder named apt-util" (with dash) and then you're doing `#include <apt_util/unicode_utils.h>` (with underscore). Which is correct? Or is that perhaps the actual problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you reference a header with a relative path, use `"` instead of `<>`

```
#include "apt_util/unicode_utils.h"
```

You also seem to have a wrong path : `apt_util` instead of `apt-util`.

Answer (score 1):

Give your compiler a hint about the base path of your include directories, e.g.

```
gcc -I/usr/local/src ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directory `apt_util` is a subdirectory of your current working directory shouldn't you be using `#include "apt_util/unicode_utils.h"` instead?